# C# about return integer array

Tags: c#

When I write C# code return the integer array,why it just output 3? it cannot random number.Please help me, thanks!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(3);
}
static int[] RandomArray(int items)
{
    int[] array = new int[items];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand.Next(100, 200);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(3);`

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var output = RandomArray(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(output[i]);
    }       

    Console.WriteLine();
}

static int[] RandomArray(int items)
{
    int[] array = new int[items];

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand.Next(100, 200);
    }

    return array;
}
```

In `output` variable, you will get array. You can use it further.

Comment: Yeah, someone has a bee in their bonnet

Comment: exactly, I was about to say the same. Someone is very frustrated. :D

Comment: yeah.. looks like y'all got your rep points back though. Not sure why I'm still downvoted :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

The problem is you were just writing `3` to the console

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(var item in RandomArray(3))
       Console.WriteLine(item);
}

static int[] RandomArray(int items)
{
    int[] array = new int[items];

    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
        array[i] = rand.Next(100, 200);

    return array;
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/15AUxE)

---

[Random Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Console.WriteLine Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You know, id usually worry about the down votes, however, i need 3 more to get back to a multiple of 10

Comment: You deserve too :)

Answer (score 0):

`Main` is the [entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) in a C# application.  Main is called by the common language runtime (CLR) at the start of your program's execution.  In other words, `Main` is called automatically. `RandomArray` is also a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods).  However, it is not an Entry point and therefore it will not be called automatically.  You have to call `RandomArray` from main in order for the method to execute.

Right now your program is effectively just:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(3);
}
```

The rest of the code is just sitting around doing nothing.

In order to fix this problem you need to call `RandomArray` from `Main`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(3);
    RandomArray(5);
}
```

And if you also want to output more data to the console then you can do something like:

```
static int[] RandomArray(int items)
{
    int[] array = new int[items];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand.Next(100, 200);
        Console.WriteLine($"{array[i]} inserted into array");
    }

    return array;
}
```

Presumably you also want to do something with the return value of `RandomArray`.  Modify `Main` to assign the return value to a variable.  Then you can do something with the result:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(3);
    int[] result = RandomArray(5);
    foreach (var element in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```